# With forecasting - Can we edit forecast of users

Tags: forecast

With forecasting (Customizable/ Collaborative) can we (i believe only forecast managers with Override Forecast permission) edit the forecast of users.

The reason why i was asking, because i was little confused after watching a youtube video on forecasting where at the end it says, "you can only change/adjust the forecast  aggregate but not on each individual opportunities of users who are direct reports to Forecast manager.

Can someone please clarify

Answer (score 1):

A customizable forecast is more than a sum of current opportunity amounts (or expected amounts).  The option to adjust forecasts allows managers to incorporate systemic effects such as business climate, inventory, or, more commonly, a sales reps propensity to over- or under-promise.

For example, if my sales rep Alice consistently beats her forecast, I can adjust the aggregate amount upward.  What I can't do is pick specific opportunities and adjust their amounts. I can move them back and forth along forecast categories ("Alice thinks this is still uncertain, but I know for whatever reason that it's going to happen"), but not adjust an amount -- even if I know it's wrong.